# Is there an example that proves $( \exists x)(P(x) \land Q(x))$ is not equivalent to $( \exists x)P(x) \land ( \exists x)Q(x)$

Tags: logic

Is there an example that proves $(\exists x)(P(x) \land Q(x))$ is not equivalent to $(\exists x)P(x) \land (\exists x)Q(x)$?

Comment: Let $\{0, 1\}$ be the universe. Let $P(x)$ be "$x = 0$", and $Q(x)$ be "$x = 1$".

Comment: Reviewer: Please reject the incorrect edit I proposed; I can't find a way to retract it.

Comment: There exist very, very many possible examples as the answers and Tunococ's comment have more-or-less hinted at.

Answer (score 6):

Let $P(x)\equiv (x=1)$ and $Q(x)\equiv (x=0)$ and use the fact that  $1\ne 0$

Answer (score 5):

Let $P(x)$ be the claim that $x$ is an odd integer. Let $Q(x)$ be the claim that $x$ is an even integer. Then $\exists x(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$ is false while $\exists x P(X) \wedge \exists x Q(x)$ is true.